# Installing and compiling using the Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

So I thought upgrading Qt and Qt Creator was a good idea since I used an older version of both.

I re-installed everything as I should and realized that Qt 5 is only for VS2010 for Windows which I have never worked with since I have been sticking with minGW up to this point,

I then realized my problems that my project wouldn't compile and run so I tried to download the 4.8.4 version with minGW, but that complained that:

```
"The installer could not find a valid c:\MinGW32\include\w32api.h
(Only versions with W32API3.13 are supported)"
```

and further I did not get creator when I installed it either.

Any help that would either let me go back to 4.8.8 minGW or a simple straight forward way using Qt creator with VS2010 would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved parts of my own issue (at least enough to answer this problem).

1: Download and install latest minGW installer and add ';C:\MinGW\bin' to the system variable 'path'.

2: Download the Qt 4.8.4 and install it (Does not come with Qt Creator) and add'C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin' to the system variable 'path'.

3: Download the latest Qt Creator, launch it and go:
tools -> options -> build & run
From there choose the correct Qt version by pointing to the Qmake in the Bin folder (C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin in this case)
Also make sure it auto detects minGW compiler, if it does not show up I am not sure what to do.

4: If you are including a project from other Qt versions you might have to delete the users.pro file (not the .pro file) to get it to compile properly.

Last issue is that I do not have any debugger, but the program compiles in the /release folder (if you put CONFIG += release in the pro file) and I can run it by using the .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Using MSVS 2010 as the compiler isn't too hard.

Download Visual Studio Express 2010.

Install it, and now you have MSVS 2010 compiler available.

The compiler should be located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin` or somewhere similar at `cl.exe`.

Setting up the latest version of Qt built against MSVC 2010, with the latest Qt Creator isn't too bad, either.  In Tools > Options > Build and Run > Kits, find your Qt qmake installation, and in Tools > Options > Build and Run > Compiler, find your compiler.

Now you can use the amazing Qt 5 instead of sticking in the past with 4.8  (even though Qt 4.8 is awesome and works really well, too).

Hope that helps.